# Issue finding xpath c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

How to write `xpath` for the below HTML:

```
<span id="filename_548948">Test DC Email </span>
```

The following xpath doesn't seem to work:

```
Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//span[text() = '" + nameOfEmail + "']")).Click();
```

Comment: It looks like there is an additional space after "Email" that you may not have accounted for.

Comment: Try using `//span[contains(text(),""nameOfEmail")]` instead

Comment: Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[text() = '" + nameOfEmail + " ']")).Click();   worked by adding extra space. Thanks All for your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on what the string nameOfEmail contains.

You have an xpath query on exact text. Meaning every character should be the same in the search as on the webpage.

So if `string nameOfEmail = "Test DC Email "`

It will search properly.

Also, losing the `.` in front of the `//` might help

Comment: Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[contains(text(),'"+nameOfEmail+"']")) doesn't seem to work. You are right nameOfEmail = "Test DC Email"

Comment: Did you add a space after Email? As in: "Test DC Email " blank space after the word Email

Comment: @Tanya remove + and " there
Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[contains(text(),'nameOfEmai']"))

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have shared you can use the following `xpath` :

```
//with a constant string
Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[starts-with(@id,'filename_') and contains(normalize-space(), 'Test DC Email')]")).Click();
//with a variable string
Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[starts-with(@id,'filename_') and contains(normalize-space(), '" + nameOfEmail + "')]")).Click();
```

Comment: If you are going to use `contains()`, there's no need to use `normalize-space()`.